# jQuery Datatable no filtrar una fila en especifico

Tags: jquery, datatables

Buenas tengo mi datatable version `1.10.19`, El detalle es que no quiero que se pueda filtrar mi ultima fila y todas las demás si, `filter: true`, espero me halla especificado bien y pudieran ayudarme encontré esto:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        if (data[1] != 'Total') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    });
```

pero no me funciono ya que me quita mi ultima fila y eso no quiero solo que no se pueda filtrar la ultima fila

Así lleno mi data table

```
var maximo = data.length;
    dataset = [];
          for (var i =0; i<data.length; i++) {

          var total=0;
          total = Number(data[i].real) + Number(data[i].nore) + Number(data[i].ca) + Number(data[i].pe);
          tot+=total;


          real+=parseInt(data[i].rea);
          noreal+=parseInt(data[i].nore);
          sca+=parseInt(data[i].ca);
          spe+=parseInt(data[i].pe);


          dataset[i] = [];

          dataset[i].push(num++);

          dataset[i].push(data[i].as);
          dataset[i].push(data[i].rea);
          dataset[i].push(data[i].nore);
          dataset[i].push(data[i].ca);
          dataset[i].push(data[i].pe);
          dataset[i].push(total);
          dataset[i].push(pRe(parseInt(data[i].rea),0,total));
          dataset[i].push(porc(total,elem));
          dataset[i].push(data[i].hus);
    }


            maximo+1;
            var numero_l = num-1;
            var totalporce = numero_l*elem;

            dataset[maximo] =[];

            dataset[maximo].push(num++);

            dataset[maximo].push('Total');
            dataset[maximo].push(real);
            dataset[maximo].push(noreal);
            dataset[maximo].push(sca);
            dataset[maximo].push(spe);
            dataset[maximo].push(tot);
            dataset[maximo].push(pRe(real,0,tot));
            dataset[maximo].push(porc(tot,totalporce));
            dataset[maximo].push('Todos');


      if(table_c) {
        table_c.destroy();
        $('#'+id_table+'').empty();
        table_c = null;
      }

      if (table_c == null) {
          table_c = $('#'+id_table+'').DataTable({
            data: dataset,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copyHtml5',
                'excelHtml5',
                'csvHtml5',
                'pdfHtml5'
            ],
            select: true,
            rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {

              if(data[0]==1 || data[0]==3 ||data[0]==5 ||data[0]==7|| data[0]==9|| data[0]==11 ||data[0]==13 ||data[0]==15||data[0]==17||data[0]==19){
                  var len=9;

                  for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                $('td:eq('+i+')', row).css('background-color', '#F9F9F9');

                }
              }

              $(row).find('td:eq(0)').css('cursor','pointer');
              $(row).find('td:eq(1)').css('cursor','pointer');
              $(row).find('td:eq(2)').css('cursor','pointer');
              $(row).find('td:eq(3)').css('cursor','pointer');
              $(row).find('td:eq(4)').css('cursor','pointer');
              $(row).find('td:eq(5)').css('cursor','pointer');
              $(row).find('td:eq(6)').css('cursor','pointer');
              $(row).find('td:eq(7)').css('cursor','pointer');
              $(row).find('td:eq(8)').css('cursor','pointer');



              $(row).find('td:eq(9)').css('display','none');

              $(row).find('td:eq(0)').addClass('nombre_class');
              $(row).find('td:eq(0)').attr("data-ids",data[9]);
              $(row).find('td:eq(1)').addClass('nombre_class');
              $(row).find('td:eq(1)').attr("data-ids",data[9]);
              $(row).find('td:eq(2)').addClass('nombre_class');
              $(row).find('td:eq(2)').attr("data-ids",data[9]);
              $(row).find('td:eq(3)').addClass('nombre_class');
              $(row).find('td:eq(3)').attr("data-ids",data[9]);
              $(row).find('td:eq(4)').addClass('nombre_class');
              $(row).find('td:eq(4)').attr("data-ids",data[9]);
              $(row).find('td:eq(5)').addClass('nombre_class');
              $(row).find('td:eq(5)').attr("data-ids",data[9]);
              $(row).find('td:eq(6)').addClass('nombre_class');
              $(row).find('td:eq(6)').attr("data-ids",data[9]);
              $(row).find('td:eq(7)').addClass('nombre_class');
              $(row).find('td:eq(7)').attr("data-ids",data[9]);
              $(row).find('td:eq(8)').addClass('nombre_class');
              $(row).find('td:eq(8)').attr("data-ids",data[9]);


            },


            columns: [

              { title: '#' },
              { title: 'Ase' },
              { title: 'Rea' },
              { title: 'No rea' },
              { title: 'Can' },
              { title: 'Pen' },
              { title: 'Total' },
              { title: '%' },
              { title: 'Met' },

            ],
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: '350px',
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false,
            lengthChange: false,
            info: false,
            filter: true,
            bDestroy: true,
            language: {
              search: 'Búsqueda:',
              info: "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
              infoEmpty: "No se encontró registros",
              infoFiltered: "(Filtrado por un total de _MAX_ registros)",
              zeroRecords: "No se encontró registros",
              processing: "Procesando",
              paginate: {
            first:"Primero",
            last: "Ultimo",
            next: "Siguiente",
            previous:"Anterior"
        }

            },


          });      

      } else {
        table_c.clear().rows.add(dataset).draw();
      }
```

Comment: Como agregas la fila de totales?

Comment: @alanfcm listo actualice, asi lleno mi tabla, y la fila totales, o no se si podria por ejemplo poner mi fila totales como pie de pagina